# whats is wrong with my code. its says error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) but everything looks fine to me

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/name" 
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  
       android:layout_alignLeft="true" 
       android:id="@+id/insert_name" />


    <EditText 
       android:layout_below="@+id/insert_name"
       android:id="@+id/edit_message"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
       android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
       android:tag="focusable" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

whats is wrong with my code. its says error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) but everything looks fine to me.

Comment: The opening `<RelativeLayout` tag is not closed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no closing bracket on RelativeLayout.

Comment: i thought i did have a closing bracket on RelativeLayout

Comment: It's one of those things, you are so wound up thinking about the complicated parts of the program that you completely overlook the basic error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"><!-- >missing -->

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/name" 
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  
       android:layout_alignLeft="true" 
       android:id="@+id/insert_name" />


    <EditText 
       android:layout_below="@+id/insert_name"
       android:id="@+id/edit_message"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
       android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
       android:tag="focusable" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: after i add in the brackets the error is still present

Comment: what kind of error your are getting now?